# Using Pest.rs, is there a better way to organize grammars in multiple files with an include or import?

Tags: rust, include, pest

Pest.rs makes it very easy to write grammars, but my current grammar in `complex_conf.pest` is 183 lines **and growing**. Is there an easy method to break this up such that the normal decorator macro show below,

```
#[derive(Parser)]
#[grammar = "complex_conf"]
pub struct ConfParser;
```

can still be made to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hesitate to answer, as I'm not the person to speak for the community here.

But it seems this is a known pain point which [they're planning to fixing](https://github.com/pest-parser/pest/issues/333). Issue opened in 2018.